# Why's this Flash question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I asked this question last night, and it was closed pretty quick as a duplicate:

[What did Barry Allen inherit by watching the confession video?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146957/)

of

[How can S.T.A.R. Labs afford to keep the lights on?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73204/how-can-s-t-a-r-labs-afford-to-keep-the-lights-on)

My question is about Barry's wealth, as inherited during events that took place after that other question was even asked. I'm not asking about how Barry keeps STAR Labs running.

Granted, in my original question I made an offhand comment about the building's utility bills, but that was *not* my question.

I also don't see how it could be construed to be a duplicate based on possible answers because other question is essentially "How does Wells afford STAR Labs" and mine is "How much wealth did Barry get from Wells". That's like closing:

[How much money did Harry Potter have?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12260/how-much-money-did-harry-potter-have) as a dupe of [Where did Harry's parents get all of their money from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/where-did-harrys-parents-get-all-of-their-money-from)

Comment: [Link to Reopen Votes review item for this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/95593).

Comment: Wait. 5 VTC and 3 Leave Closeds? I don't even understand. Because it contains similar key words?

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR:

It should not have been. It has been reopened since.

#### The questions

The questions by themselves aren't duplicates. They ask for different things. No matter how much or what Barry inherited, S.T.A.R. Labs still needs to keep running. Doing so just on the inheritance, would mean that eventually the money would run out.

#### The answers

The answers on "the other question" do not answer your question either. *If* it had had an answer detailing the inheritance as part of it, *then* yours would've been a duplicate. But it doesn't and it isn't.